# How to dynamically subset values and calculate the mean

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr, subset

I have a data frame containing three variables (ACC and Type and ID), where ACC refers to the accuracy of the decision, the Type refers to 30 different decision types which are repeated 15 times for each decision type over the participants and the ID refers to the participants. It looks like this:

```
ID     ACC     Type
1       1       1
1       0       3   
1       1      10
etc...
2       1       5
2       0      13
2       0      11
etc...
```

My aim is to analyze the accuracy for each decision type among the participants, and merge the data into a data frame. Such as:

```
ID    ACC_Type1     ACC_Type2 […]  ACC_Type30
1       70             65             87
2       65             50             90
etc...
```

So far I was able to calculate by subsetting individually the decision types, however, I’m looking for a smarter way to avoid typing individually the decision type value:

```
library(data.table)
library(plyr)
dt <- data.table(d,key="Type")
dt_Type1<-data.frame (aggregate(ACC~ID,data=subset(dt,Type==1),mean))
dt_Type2<-data.frame (aggregate(ACC~ID,data=subset(dt,Type==2),mean))
[]
dt_Type30<-data.frame (aggregate(ACC~ID,data=subset(dt,Type==30),mean))

total <- merge(dt_Type1,dt_Type2 […] Type30,by="ID")
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using Ananda's data, a `data.table` solution can be obtained as:

```
require(data.table)
dt <- data.table(mydf)
setkey(dt, "TYPE", "ID")
dt[, mean(ACC), by=key(dt)][, setattr(as.list(V1), 'names', 
                paste0("ACC", ID)), by=TYPE]
#    TYPE ACC1 ACC2 ACC3
# 1:    1  3.0  2.5  3.0
# 2:    2  1.5  2.0  3.0
# 3:    3  4.0  2.0  4.5
```

Comment: +1 very nice!  You can also preserve the column names using `list(paste0('ACC_', Type) = as.list(V1))`

Comment: eh, I can't _actually_ +1 I'm out of votes.  But you have my vote in spirit

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, better with `setattr(., 'names', .)`. Edited.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta, That's not the problem. The problem is that it's `as.list(.)`, you can not assign names to `as.list` without using `setNames(.)`. The equivalent in `data.table` is `setattr(., 'names', .)`. Even if it were possible, doing `list(as.list(.))` would result in  the column type to be a list.

Comment: wow, I tried it and it worked really well, thank you ALL for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing with subsetting is overkill. A basic call to `aggregate` should suffice. Additionally, to get the output you desire, you'll need to use `reshape`. Here's an example:

Sample data:

```
set.seed(1)
mydf <- data.frame(
  ID = rep(1:3, each = 6),
  ACC = sample(0:5, 18, replace = TRUE),
  TYPE = rep(1:3, 6)
)
```

Step 1: aggregate

```
temp <- aggregate(ACC ~ ID + TYPE, mydf, mean)
temp
#   ID TYPE ACC
# 1  1    1 3.0
# 2  2    1 2.5
# 3  3    1 3.0
# 4  1    2 1.5
# 5  2    2 2.0
# 6  3    2 3.0
# 7  1    3 4.0
# 8  2    3 2.0
# 9  3    3 4.5
```

Step 2: reshape

```
reshape(temp, direction = "wide", idvar = "ID", timevar = "TYPE")
#   ID ACC.1 ACC.2 ACC.3
# 1  1   3.0   1.5   4.0
# 2  2   2.5   2.0   2.0
# 3  3   3.0   3.0   4.5
```

---

#### Update

`dcast` from "reshape2" can handle this in one step with its `fun.aggregate` argument, but you'll need to do some cleanup to fix the names.

```
> dcast(mydf, ID ~ TYPE, fun.aggregate = mean, value.var = "ACC")
  ID   1   2   3
1  1 3.0 1.5 4.0
2  2 2.5 2.0 2.0
3  3 3.0 3.0 4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

if `DT`  is your `data.table`, then you can use `by=Type`
(of course posting some sample data would help generate a more accurate answer):

but something like this should work

```
  DT[,  mean(ACC),  by = Type]
```

Comment: Thank you for you comment. It gives me the mean ACC for the Types but I need the mean Type ACC for each participant. I tried to add ID after Type but it didn't work.